# Unable to debug .NET framework code in VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm trying to debug .NET code with public available symbols. I setup according instructions:

In Tools-> Options -> Debug I checked "Enable .NET framework source stepping", disabled "Enable just my Code".

In Tools-> Options -> Debug -> Symbols Load All Symbols. I checked a lot of *.pdb's appeared in this folder.

In ASP.NET MVC application I place breakpoint into Application_Start() method.

After debugger run I see call stack, see all methods in call stack (System.Web.dll). But if I try to double click it, only I see is diassembled code (or message - no source code availble).

What could be the reason ?

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved? I still have this issue

Comment: @AntonyThomas the time I met the issue, it's not been resolved (any answers did not helped). Now I'm having VS2012, but I haven't tried that on new studio.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have VS2010 SP1 installed? 
If yes than goto:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/refsourceserver/thread/41388c7b-582b-4e3f-8178-3d38a3c99639

Comment: This is the same issue I have...VS2k10 SP1 disabled support for .NET Source Debugging

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the symbols are not loading, perhaps due to a version mismatch.  I've had issues in the past getting the proper symbols to load.  I've always solved it by pointing to the Microsoft symbol server.  The article below gives step by step instructions on how to setup debugging for the .NET Framework.  In the third section "To load Framework symbols using the Modules window", it describes using the Microsoft Symbol server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx

Comment: Empty the symbol cache and try it again.

Comment: Did you also checkmark "Enable Source Server" under Tools->Options->Debugging?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue recently after a Windows 10 update. Debugger of VS 2013 was unable to find the source code and on a step in it was complaining of the missing source files: `You need to find <filename>.cs to view the source for the current call stack frame and The debugger could not locate the source file <filename>.cs`

The solution that worked for us:

```
Tools -> Imports and Export Settings -> Reset All Settings -> Select General after the save settings option.
```